# Retain cursor position after reloading the page in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using `CKEditor`(4.1) in my project.I would like to retain the cursor position in editor after user reloading the page. `CKEditor` provides

```
var bookmark = editor.selection.createBookmarks();
```

to store the cursor position.However, if i use

```
var data = editor.getData()
```

returns the following content

```
<p>one</p>

<p>two<span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></p>

<p>three</p>
```

instead of the following

```
<p>one</p>

<p>two<span data-cke-bookmakrs="1" style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></p>

<p>three</p>
```

In `config.js`, I did the following thing

```
config.extraAllowedContent = "span[data-cke-bookmark]"
```

What am i missing here?

Thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround to resolve the problem. I won't say this is a direct solution.(I haven't check for IE)

Once I create bookmark, It will return JSON object as follows

```
{collapsed: true,
endNode: undefined,
serializable: undefined,
startNode: CKEDITOR.dom.element}
```

And you can get the reference element by

```
var spanRef =  object.startNode.$;
```

And a custom attribute.

```
$(spanRef).attr('data-selection-bookmark','1')//here value '1' doesn't mean anything
```

And do the following thing in `config.js`

```
config.extraAllowedContent = "span[data-selection-bookmark]"
```

When you ask the editor content by using `editor.getData(),` It will return the following

```
<p>one</p>

<p>two<span data-selection-bookmakr="1" style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></p>

<p>three</p>
```

**The Next Half** ( After Reload or Reinit)

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_textarea');
editor.on( 'contentDom', function(){
   var ifrWin = getIframeWindow(); //You need write a code to get iframe window of CKEditor


        var range = document.createRange();

        var sel = ifrWin.getSelection();

        var doc = editor.document.$;

        var $span = $( doc.body ).find( 'span[data-selection-bookmark]' );

        range.selectNode( $span[ 0 ] );// To move the cursor before

        range.collapse(true);

        sel.addRange(range);

        $span.remove();


        ifrWin.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].focus();
});
```

Comment: Instead of using the native selection and range you should rather use the CKEditor's selection system. Create a serializable bookmark, move `data-cke-*` attributes to `data-*`, so they are not removed when getting data, get the data. Then, load this data, replace `data-*` attributes with `data-cke-*` and use [`moveToBookmark()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-moveToBookmark) method. Basically - try using as much CKEditor's stuff as possible, because this is safer.

Comment: But in general this is ok. It is not perfectly reliable, because e.g. table cell selections will leave spans in the wrong positions, so you may need to transform a range a little bit before creating a bookmark. But it should work in most cases.