# Get cursor position in CKEditor 4 within edited element's HTML

Tags: ckeditor

I use inline CKEditor for editing elements on my page. So when I click into DIV with some class, CKEditor is attached to it and when it loses focus, editor instance is destroyed. I need to insert HTML element into that DIV after CKEditor instance is destroyed - to the last position of cursor before destroying editor instance. So I basicaly need to know index of cursor in edited element's HTML, as it would be taken as a plain text (for this example below it would be 25). I don't want to modify original data.

I have HTML in my DIV like this:
`"some <span>text</span> wi|th <b>html</b> tags"` (where "|" is cursor position)

I tried to get range and extend it to the start of editable element:

```
var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ];    
range.collapse( true );
range.setStartAt( editor.editable(), CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START );
```

Here `range.endOffset` is 3 (the same as if I didn't extend range). But even if I sum up offsets of more elements, it wouldn't solve my problem, because it exclude HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use ranges if you want to use them after the editor is destroyed, because while being destroyed the editor replaces editable's inner HTML with the data and they are not the same thing.

Instead, you should create a marker for the selection before the editor is destroyed and find this marker in the data.

See this topic for ideas how to achieve that: [Retain cursor position after reloading the page in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524002/retain-cursor-position-after-reloading-the-page-in-ckeditor).

Comment: This is almost, what I have right now. But instead of `editor.getSelection().createBookmarks()` I have `editor.insertElement(tempElement)`. Problem with both solutions is, that when I check if user modified data (on editor closing), `editor.checkDirty() == true`, and so that changed HTML is sent to server. Then if user finally doesn't want to add anything on that position, I have to remove that temporal element and send data to server as changed again. It seems to me like a hack. I want to add element into data only when they really changed.

Comment: That's a job for a logic outside CKEditor, when you save data. You can for instance find this marker using regexp, replace it with empty string and remember its position in the string. And there's nothing hacky in creating that marker - that's actually the only possible solution taking into account the data processing that's happening when you get data from an editor.