# CKEditor + Meteor duplicate text when saving and flushing

Tags: meteor, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have this code to use CKEditor inline edit. The problem is that the wiki text is duplicated after the database is updated and flushed to client:

```
    #wikiedit(contenteditable="true")
        !{wikipage.text}
```

After editing and closing the editor area, a server command is executed.

```
var e = CKEDITOR.instances.wikiedit,
    save_timeout,
    save_data = function() {
        clearTimeout(save_timeout);
        Meteor.call('wiki.update', {_id: wiki_id, text: e.getSnapshot()})
        };

e.on('blur', function() {
    console.log('change event');

    clearTimeout(save_timeout);
    save_timeout = setTimeout(save_data, 2000);
});
```

Whatever I type there, when it's refreshed, in the database the text is`<p>new text</p>`, and in the CKEditor element, the old text is not removed. The new text is appended after it.

Putting code in a helper kind of helps, but the `innerHTML` there is already the old + the flushed text. But it works only if it's the current user who changed the text, otherwise the texts are different and I can't tell apart where the second copy starts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a helper that checks the state of the editor.

```
Template.document.helpers({
    ck_deduplicate: function() {
        var elt = document.getElementById('wikiedit');
        if (elt) {
            elt.innerHTML = '';
        }
        return this.wikipage.text;
    }
});
```

Page markup:

```
    #wikiedit(contenteditable="true")
        {{{ ck_deduplicate }}}
```

## Live Saving When Typing

With some smarter code I set it up to save and update the content of an opened editor. The final solution with live saving came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524002/retain-cursor-position-after-reloading-the-page-in-ckeditor).

For Meteor the setup is below. First, the CKEditor setup. Before saving the document we create a bookmark and manipulate DOM to make that element be saved (with a config change).

```
Template.single_doc.rendered = function() {
    console.log('rendered')
    var wiki_id = Router.current().data().wikipage._id,
        // the method that does the main job of setting up CKEditor
        assign_change = function(ev) {
            var e = ev.editor,

                // timeout is stored to cancel if key is pressed within 2 seconds
                save_timeout,

                // data saving function
                save_data = function() {
                    clearTimeout(save_timeout);
                    var bm = e.getSelection().createBookmarks()[0];
                    $(bm.startNode).attr('data-selection-bookmark','1');

                    console.log('update', {_id: wiki_id, text: e.getSnapshot()});
                    Meteor.call('doc.update', {_id: wiki_id, text: e.getSnapshot()})
                    };

            // config updated to allow spans with our attribute
            e.on('configLoaded', function() {
                e.config.extraAllowedContent = "span[data-selection-bookmark]";
            });

            // watch document changed
            e.on('change', function() {
                console.log('change event');
                clearTimeout(save_timeout);
                save_timeout = setTimeout(save_data, 2000);
            });
        },

        // unfortunately, had to wrap `editor.on('change')` in the assign_change above
        // because when `.rendered` is triggered, CKEditor is not loaded yet.
        // Have to wait for it.
        assign_event = function() {
            if (typeof(CKEDITOR) == 'undefined') {
                setTimeout(assign_event, 100);
                return;
            }

            CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', assign_change);
        };


    assign_event();

}
```

Then, the helper that manually updates the CKEditor data and moves cursor where needed.

```
Template.single_doc.helpers({
    ck_deduplicate: function() {
        // the helper either outputs the text into the document on document init
        // or when the template is re-rendered, it updates CKEditor
        var elt = document.getElementById('wikiedit');

        // if dom works, then it's an update, should work with CKEDITOR
        if (elt) {

            // get its instance and create a range object (selection tool in CKE)
            var e = CKEDITOR.instances.wikiedit,
                range = e.createRange();

            // load the data
            e.loadSnapshot(this.wikipage.text);

            // inside the text there is <span> with a bookmark
            var sel = e.getSelection(),
                // find the bookmark
                $span = $(e.document.$).find('[data-selection-bookmark]');

            // select before it
            range.setStartBefore(new CKEDITOR.dom.node($span[0]));
            // collapse to the start
            range.collapse(true);
            // do selection
            range.select();
            // remove the bookmark data
            $(e.document.$).find('[data-selection-bookmark]').remove();
            return '';
        }

        return this.wikipage.text;
    }
});
```

One drawback is that it won't work with 2 people editing this simultaneously. They'll steal cursor one from another all the time. For that, a relative position stored in memory should work better. But this one is enough as a temporary workaround and a starting point. Hope this helps the others.